# C language: Header inclusion makes unexpected behavior

Tags: c, header-files

I have a serious problem now, and really want to find out what the root cause is.

Function source file:

```
//function.c
#include "function.h"
void FunctionA (int tiFrame)
{
     printf ("%d", tiFrame);
}
```

Function header file:

```
//function.h
extern void FunctionA (int tiFrame);
```

A stupid outside header file:

```
// stupid.h
#define tiFrame TIFRAME
```

Application:

```
//application.c
#include "stupid.h"
#include "function.h"

void App2 ()
{
    FunctionA (10);
}
```

The result: FunctionA always printed "0" (zero value)!

Now, I changed the application file:

```
//application.c
#include "function.h"
#include "stupid.h"

void App2 ()
{
    FunctionA (10);
}
```

The result: FunctionA always printed "10" (correct!)!

Have anyone had any idea about the root cause?

Comment: See the preprocessed output of application.c. It may give some hint.

Comment: @KhangLe what is TIFRAME?

Comment: @mangusta: #define TIFRAME 15. By the way, the definition of "tiFrame" must be removed, but it was not, so I am stuck with it.

Comment: In `FunctionA()` in line `printf ("%d", tiFrame);` the preprocessor would change `tiFrame` to `TIFRAME` and which is probably 0.

Comment: Most likely, there is more in the header files than you have shown.

Comment: @Rohan just wanted to print the same thing : ))

Comment: @Rohan: TIFRAME is not 0, unfortunately! With the current header inclusion, function.c must not "see" the definition of "tiFrame". It is frustrated.

Comment: change name of argument from tiFrame to arg_tiFrame...

Comment: @ChuckCottrill interesting thing here is not how to solve the issue, interesting thing is to clarify why it happens :)

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: I did the same as a workaround. But, how could it be?

Answer (score 1):

You have a collision between a #define which has leaked from the "stupid.h" header, and collides with your function definition.

You could insert a printf to find the value of TIFRAME...

```
printf("%d\n", TIFRAME);
```

Or, more cleverly, use symbol pasting to convert TIFRAME into a string...

Or, just fix/avoid. Your inclusion of "stupid.h" here expands the #define for tiFrame...

```
#define tiFrame TIFRAME
```

So, avoid this collision,

```
//function.c
#include "function.h"
void FunctionA (int arg_tiFrame)
{
     printf ("%d", arg_tiFrame);
}
```

You don't even need to mention an arg name here,

```
//function.h
extern void FunctionA (int);
```

Or, you could undefine the tiFrame prior to your function...

```
//stupid.h declares tiFrame, gotta avoid that
#define CleverAvoidance tiFrame
#undef tiFrame
//function.c
#include "function.h"
void FunctionA (int tiFrame)
{
     printf ("%d", tiFrame);
}
//and put it back the way it was, or just fugeddaboudit
#define tiFrame CleverAvoidance
```

Answer (score 0):

The different behavior is coused by `preprocess` program.

**CASE1**:

```
#include "stupid.h"
#include "function.h"
```

After `preprocess`：

```
#define tiFrame TIFRAME
extern void FunctionA (int TIRAME); //the parameter is changed to const
void App2 ()
{
    FunctionA (10); //the call parameter is still the const TIRAME
}
```

**CASE2**:

```
#include "function.h"
#include "stupid.h"
```

After `preprocess`：

```
extern void FunctionA (int tiFrame); //the parameter is still the varibale
#define tiFrame TIFRAME
void App2 ()
{
    FunctionA (10); //the parameter is 10 in this case
}
```

**PS:** You'd better not write such confusing code. Follow the `KISS` priciple, couse other people may read and use your code.

Comment: Hello! It is a real situation in my project. Because of confidentiality, I had to change the function name and file name. You developed your components such a long time, then now you figured out that some new macros had the same name as yours.

Comment: If you use `UPCASE` for `MACROS`, `downcase` for `parameters`. You won't have this problem.